# Dynamic SSR false stack in page source in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to disable this stack in page source in production mode in NextJS 12? I tried to search but didn't find any solutions.

```
    at Suspense
    at LoadableComponent (D:\nep-meds\public\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\loadable.js:85:9)
    at BloodBank (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/blood-bank/index.jsx:51:22)
    at main
    at div
    at AppLayout (webpack-internal:///./src/containers/Layout/AppLayout.js:28:22)
    at CheckoutProvider (webpack-internal:///./src/context/Checkout/CheckoutProvider.js:50:29)
    at CartProvider (webpack-internal:///./src/context/Cart/CartProvider.js:68:25)
    at LayoutProvider (webpack-internal:///./src/context/Layout/LayoutProvider.js:22:27)
    at AuthProvider (webpack-internal:///./src/context/Auth/AuthProvider.js:45:25)
    at MainContext (webpack-internal:///./src/context/index.js:19:24)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./src/components/Error/index.js:24:9)
    at main
    at App (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.jsx:53:16)
    at ae (D:\nep-meds\public\node_modules\styled-components\dist\styled-components.cjs.js:1:13282)
    at StyleRegistry (D:\nep-meds\public\node_modules\styled-jsx\dist\index\index.js:449:36)
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (D:\nep-meds\public\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\adapters.js:60:11)
    at AppContainer (D:\nep-meds\public\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:290:29)
    at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (D:\nep-meds\public\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:326:57)
    at div
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. This may not be greater approach but instead of using next/dynamic i created own custom component same like react-no-ssr module.

```
import React from "react";

const NoSSR = ({ children, fallback }) => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) {
    return fallback;
  }

  return children;
};

export default NoSSR;
```